# adding some styles to react-d3-cloud

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, styling

I need some examples of style implementation of react-d3-cloud.

```
<WordCloud
ref="olala"
height={this.state.totalHeight}
padding={0}
style={{"background-color":"red"}}
width={this.state.totalWidth}
font={'Impact'}
data={this.renderSize()}
// fontSizeMapper={fontSizeMapper}
rotate={rotate}
```

/>

Answer (score 0):

if you only need background colour then you can use the following approach.

```
 <div
    style={{
      background: "red"
    }}
  >
    <WordCloud
      data={data}
      fontSizeMapper={fontSizeMapper}
      rotate={rotate}
    />
  </div>
```